# Can we specify picture name after taking picture from cordova through navigator.camera.getpicture?

Tags: cordova

I am taking picture through cordova using navigator.camera.getpicture.
can we specify picture name for the image?

Answer (score 0):

Function camera.getPicture opens the device's default camera application so that the user can take a picture (if Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, which is the default). Once the photo is taken, the camera application closes and your application is restored.

If Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, then a photo chooser dialog is shown, from which a photo from the album can be selected.

The return value will be sent to the cameraSuccess function, in one of the following formats, depending on the cameraOptions you specify:

```
A String containing the Base64 encoded photo image (default).

A String representing the image file location on local storage.
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ko/2.0.0/cordova/camera/camera.getPicture.html

Comment: Your answer does not make any sense or solution to the question.